# Print path of input file

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a macro that imports to my main workbook some data from other workbooks, which are stored in different folders, and keeps the link instead of doing the simplye copy-paste xlvalues. Thereby an extract of the code

```
With Master.Sheets("Sheet1")
     .Activate
     .Range("F4").Select
     .Paste Link:=True
End With
```

In this way, the cells of the workbook "Master" display the link, for example:

```
"'C:\Users\Documents\[Input.xlsx]Sheet1'!E29"
```

Is there a macro code which would allow me to extract from the abovementioned link only the path to the relevant workbook (i.e. `'C:\Users\Documents\[Input.xlsx]`) so that I can print it in a summary report to display the path of the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next piece of code:

```
Sub extractPathFromLink()
  Dim x As String, path As String
  x = "'C:\Users\Documents\[Input.xlsx]Sheet1'!E29"
  path = Split(Split(x, "'")(1), "]")(0) & "]"
  MsgBox path
End Sub
```

Edited:

The next version returns the real workbook path:

```
Sub extractPath()
  Dim x As String, path As String
  x = "'C:\Users\Documents\[Input.xlsx]Sheet1'!E29"
  path = Replace(Split(Split(x, "'")(1), "]")(0), "[", "")
  MsgBox path
End Sub
```

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: I simple copied the string form the question. Now I can see it also contains that back slash... I will insert it. Anyhow, the logic of the code is not affected by its missing or existence. Thanks! It probably will be better to retrieve a real path 'C:\Users\Documents\Input.xlsx', which is simple to be obtained if she wants it in this way.